each JS file has 3 files js es5js and es5minjs why
Haven't too much experience with
fileName1.js
fileName1.es5.js
fileName1.es5.min.js 

so please bear with
I need to make changes to a number of js files on our mvc project.
So each JS file has the 3 files (above).
When I make a change to the orignial, do I need to also change this in the other 2?
Also, ive just been brought onto this project, but in the .cshtml file where the js file is being referenced, sometimes it will reference the fileName.js and other times it will ref the fileName.es5.min.js
Was this a mistake on the developers side, im assuming every ref should have been to the fileName.es5.min.js file??
I get what the 'es5.min.js' does, its compressed with no white space to save loading time etc... but whats the point of the 'es5.js' file?,
Making the change of the file mentioned solves my task, but the other 2 js files for that particular file wont have the update then
My question is Do I mannually need to change all 3 files? or for example when I change the orignial file, and somehow during the build the other 2 files get updated, or is there somewhere I drop in the main file and can get 3 outputted files? what do I do?
any advice appreciated thank you for replies

JavaScript files marked as ES5 can be useful to indicate developers what standards were followed when writing the code in this file. Web site uglifyjs.net we usual use for a create min file.

It is usually not recommended to connect both minimized (min) and normal  file at the same time to avoid duplication code.

I'm not familiar with asp.net but if the extra files are produced by a build script, then they will be updated during build (after the original is modified). To be sure, you can check the diff between "before" and "after" versions of the generated files.
